# Is there an easy way for a kubernetes service to have oauth 2.0 implemented for server side?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress

I have a REST API service in kubernetes. Is there any easy plugin or config for implementing OAuth 2.0 for this service?

Can we also leverage Istio or NGINX-ingress controller for this task?

I found somethings online regarding this, but none of the resources seem to clearly explain the OAuth2.0 serverside implementation.

- istio: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/
- k8s: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely it's one of the Istio's built-in security features, the end-user authentication with JSON Web Token (JWT). Citing official documentation:

> Origin authentication, also known as end-user authentication: verifies
>   the original client making the request as an end-user or device. Istio
>   enables request-level authentication with JSON Web Token (JWT)
>   validation and a streamlined developer experience for open source
>   OpenID Connect provider ORY Hydra, Keycloak, Auth0, Firebase Auth,
>   Google Auth, and custom auth.

Please jump to [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication) task driven example of End-user authentication with Istio, to have a better understanding how it works in practice.